# mysql copy column data type to another table

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to copy a column's structure from an already populated table to a new table which is empty? I'm only asking about copying the structure without the data

Example:
We have a table

```
CREATE TABLE `animals` (
`animal` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
   `food` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`animal`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB

INSERT INTO `animals` (`animal`, `food`) VALUES
('cat', 'chips'),
('dog', 'bones'),
('shark', 'ppl');
```

And a new table called `predators` for which I want to make just one column but with the same data type as the animals' column type.

Is there a way to combine the SHOW COLUMNS/FIELDS with the CREATE TABLE or create the table with a column that has some kind of type like VARCHAR(17) and then ALTER  CHANGE it to the same type as the `animal` column?

I know this is a simple question but i haven't had any luck finding the answer to it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you wish to copy the data:

```
INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2) 
SELECT col1, col2 FROM otherTable
```

If you wish to copy the table structure:

> Use `LIKE` to create an empty table based on the definition of another table, including any column attributes and indexes defined in the original table:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;
> ```
>
> The copy is created using the same version of the table storage format as the original table. The SELECT privilege is required on the original table.

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

If you want to copy the structure and the data:

```
CREATE TABLE animals2 AS 
SELECT *
FROM animals ;
```

And if you want to copy the structure (but not all columns) without data:

```
CREATE TABLE animals2 AS 
SELECT animal                -- only the columns you want
FROM animals 
WHERE FALSE;                 -- and no data
```

Comment: Yes thought of that but i don't want to copy the table and drop columns from it. I want to see other possible ways. Still, thank you

Comment: `CREATE TABLE animals2 AS SELECT animal FROM animals WHERE FALSE;` will create a new table with one column only (and not copy any data).

Comment: But the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint will not be carried over (I think.)

Comment: @ypercube Thank you - exactly what i was looking for. Yes, the primary key doesn't get carried over but it's ok, it works for several columns too. I wish I could mark your comment as an accepted answer though

Comment: @ypercube I'll make sure to send you a check for the accept rep.

Comment: Thanks allot for the post, but how do I copy the table structure and change a columns name?

Comment: @NickPeelman You will have to use `ALTER` syntax after the table is copied to rename the columns.

Comment: For me the first query worked only without ```VALUES``` - ```INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2 FROM otherTable```