# Copy column definition from one table to another?

Tags: mysql, ddl

I want to copy a column (definition, not data) from one table to another. Add the column if it doesn't exist in destination table, or better yet, modify it accordingly if it exists.

Tried to google but everything seems to be about either copying the data rather than the definition, or about copying an entire table using `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ...`.

Thus far [the closest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14913589/49318) I could find is this:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS 
SELECT field4, field7                -- only the columns you want
FROM table 
WHERE FALSE;                 -- and no data
```

But I need to copy columns to existing tables. So I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE table2 AS 
SELECT field4, field7                -- only the columns you want
FROM table 
WHERE FALSE;                 -- and no data
```

But apparently it refused to work.

Is there something like this?

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN column2 LIKE table2.column5
```

Any way to achieve this in MySQL?

Comment: No. `CREATE TABLE` can be created out of a `SELECT` query, but `ALTER TABLE` has a different syntax that doesn't include a `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to **Dump** the table and then you can use **ALTER** command to create the new table.

Dumping the table gives back the query to **CREATE** the table.

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  customerId varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  firstName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  middleName varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  lastName varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_estonian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;`

USE the same to **ALTER** an existing table, (say `customerinfo`)

```
`ALTER TABLE customerinfo ADD COLUMN (
  customerId varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  firstName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  middleName varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  lastName varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_estonian_ci DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with queries this is the way:

Get the properties of the old column with:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `mytable` where Field=`mycolumn`
```

Use mysqli_fetch_array to get the field properties in the variable $row.

Now create the new query:

```
$qry = "ALTER TABLE othertable";
$qry .= " ADD `newcol`"; /* name of new column; $row['Field'] works too */
$qry .= " ".$row["Type"]; /* example value: varchar(255) */
if($row["Null"] == "NO")
    $qry .= " NOT NULL";
if($row["Default"] != "")
    $qry .= " default '".$row["Default"]."'";
```

The $row contains also an Extra field but that can give problems with auto_increase.